# iOS Generic type for codable property in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, codable

I need to get a generic variable for a struct for parsing a JSON

but there is an  error that I am getting
 **Type 'BaseJsonModel' does not conform to protocol 'Codable**

Below is my struct

```
  struct BaseJsonStruct<T>: Codable {
    let info: String
    let data: T
 }
```

Error:- Type 'BaseJsonModel' does not conform to protocol 'Codable'

Answer (score 59, accepted):

`T` must also conform to `Codable`

```
struct BaseJsonStruct<T : Codable> : Codable {
    let info: String
    let data: T
}
```

Comment: If I used   let item = try? decoder.decode(BaseJsonStruct.self, from: data).  than I get error - Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred

Comment: do you have any idea of the same

Comment: You have to specify the static type for example `decoder.decode(BaseJsonStruct<String>.self, from: data`

Comment: tried but the value in variable comes as nil let itm1 = try? decoder.decode(BaseJsonStruct<T>.self, from: data). But it compiles now alteast

Comment: No, at the moment you use a generic you **must** specify the static type. `BaseJsonStruct<T>` is not possible, it must be `BaseJsonStruct<String>` or `BaseJsonStruct<Int>` or something else which conforms to `Codable`. `Codable` relies on concrete types. The decoder cannot decode dynamic types.

Comment: @vadian great answer but in my case it is BaseJsonStruct<T> and I got stuck with it for quite so long. Give me your hands please to solve this issue.