# How to specify field for mapping data from Alamofire with Codable object?

Tags: json, swift, alamofire, decodable

For my APIManager.swift

```
APIManager.manager.request(urlEncoded, method: useMethod, parameters: params, encoding: requestEncoding, headers: headers)
    .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
    .responseJSON { response in
    switch response.result {
    case .success(let json):
        ///
    case .failure(let error):
        ///
    }
}
```

And my API JSON response

```json
{
    "code": 200,
    "status": "success",
    "response_data": {
        "name": "testing"
    }
}
```

my model

```
struct TesterModel: Codable {
    var name: String
}
```

I need to map object with codeable protocol but map only on `reponse_data` field from API response. How to map it from `.responseJSON`?

Comment: Custom `init(from: Decoder)` for `TesterModel` to let you skip the top level `response_data`?

Comment: @Larme can u give me some example code?

Comment: Alamofire can decode JSON directly with the `responseDecodable` modifier. In any case you have to specify the struct representing the root object.

Comment: `response_data` value can be different if I read correctly another comment? So you could have `TesterModel2` , `TesterModel3` etc? If so, a Generic type on a high level wrapper might do the work. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49529208/ios-generic-type-for-codable-property-in-swift and use the `responseDecodable` to specify your expected output: `Wrapper<TestModel>.self` etc?

Answer (score 1):

You can use "CodingKeys" for specific fields

```
enum CodingKeys
```

Like this:

```
struct Landmark: Codable {
    var name: String
    var foundingYear: Int
    var location: Coordinate
    var vantagePoints: [Coordinate]
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name = "title"
        case foundingYear = "founding_date"
        
        case location
        case vantagePoints
    }
}
```

Also for decoding you can use JSONDecoder()

```
guard let response = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Landmark, data) else { return nil }
```

See More Here [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types)

Answer (score 0):

You can create another model like this:

```
struct APIResponse: Codable {
    var code: Int
    var status: String
    var responseData: TesterModel
}

struct TesterModel: Codable {
    var name: String
}
```

And then you can just do that:

```
APIManager.manager.request(urlEncoded, method: useMethod, parameters: params, encoding: requestEncoding, headers: headers)
            .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
            .responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
                guard let data = response.data else {
                    return
                }
                do {
                    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(APIResponse.self, from: data)
                }
                catch {
                    
                }
        }
```

Comment: I have multiple responsedata type and I have a error case like `code` be 400. This way is not properly I think. Thank u for your reply.